# How to manage offline maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm making an Android app that needs to use maps, even if the user is offline. I know that google maps can't be stored for so I tried with Mobile Atlas Creator to genereate tiles and include them whithin the app, but the providers are very limited, they didn't have data for my country.

So my question is what is the best aproach for this type of situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an OpenStreetMaps controller (like osmdroid) and Google Maps tiles. According to the Google Maps TOS (10.1.3.b), it seems that you can use a portion of maps if you cache it temporarily and securely